# How to pass the value in the dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

How to pass the value in the dictionary.

model:-

```
class cartresultModel: NSObject {

    var totalsum:String!
    var totalid:String!

    init?(dictionary:JSONDictionary) {
      guard let totalsum = dictionary["totalsum"] as? String,
        let totalid = dictionary["totalid"] as? String else {
            return
        }

        self.totalsum = totalsum
        self.totalid = totalid
        print( self.totalsum )
    }

}
```

datasourcemodel:-

```
 class CartresultDataSource: NSObject {
        var dataListArray:Array<cartresultModel>? = []


        init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
            super.init()
            var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
            if array == nil{

                newArray = self.getJsonDataStored222()
            }
            else{
                newArray = array!

            }

            var datalist:Array<cartresultModel> = []
            for dict in newArray{

                let model = cartresultModel(dictionary: dict)

                datalist.append(model!)
            }
            self.dataListArray = datalist
        }



    }

    typealias dummyDataSource222 =  CartresultDataSource
    extension dummyDataSource222{

        func getJsonDataStored222() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

            let jsonArray = [["totalid":"1","totalsum":"0"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

            return jsonArray
        }






    }
```

my viewmodel:-

```
   class CartresultViewModel: NSObject {

        var datasourceModel:CartresultDataSource


        var no: [String] = []


        var filteredListArray:Array<cartresultModel>? = []


        init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: CartresultDataSource) {
            datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)



        }



        func datafordisplay(objectatindex index: Int) ->  cartresultModel{
            return  (datasourceModel.dataListArray?[index])!

        }

        func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

            return datasourceModel.dataListArray!.count
        }





    }
```

my cartdisplayresult view:-

```
class CartdisplayView: UIView {


     @IBOutlet weak var totalresult:UILabel!




    override init(frame:CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    }


    func setcartdetailData(cartsdetail:QM_cartresultModel)
    {
      //  self.totalresult.text = cartsdetail.totalsum



    }

}
```

From other viewcontroller i have send the total price amount in self.no(this is in cartresultviewmodel).

Suppose `the output is ["[123]"]`

From this output i need to take the value 123 .AS my cartdatasource:-

let jsonArray = [["totalid":"1","totalsum":"0"]] as Array>

Here totalSum = 0

But i need to pass 123 in totalsum key.Means i need to get totalsum = 123
How to pass.So how to set this value in cartresultview.means:-self.totalresult.text = ?

Comment: You would get better answers if you added a tag for the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

**you can do this like**

```
jsonArray[0]["totalsum"] = "123"
```

**its better to put in if let for ignoring nil crash**

```
 if let _ = jsonArray[0]["totalsum"]  {
       jsonArray[0]["totalsum"] = "123"
      }
```

Comment: how can give according to my code.and where did i need to give.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to understand what you are trying to do and there is basically no JSON involved (yet?). If you define your array as

```
let: [[String : Any]]  jsonArray = [["totalid":"1","totalsum":"0"]]
```

this statement

```
jsonArray[0]["totalsum"] = 123
```

will yield a simple

```
Cannot assign through subscript: 'jsonArray' is a 'let' constant
```

from the compiler. It is a little strange for people coming from JavaScript, but the default data structure of Swift is *immutable*.

Easy enough to solve:

```
var jsonArray : [[String : Any]] = [["totalid":"1","totalsum":"0"]]
jsonArray[0]["totalsum"] = 123
```

you can assign whatever you want to a `var`iable if it is defined accordingly. I *guess* you would like to compute your "totalsum" from whatever you load in the array, but you would have to show your intentions more clearly in order to be sure.

As a general piece of advice I would stick to the `Codable` protocol for things you *actually* want to parse from JSON, your Swift code will be a lot less messy and you won't have to riddle it with casts and optional unwrappings.